# Analysing a pseudocode

Tags: for-loop, queue, pseudocode

```
Algorithm 1. QUEUESTUFF(n)
Input: Integer n
1) Let Q = an empty Queue
2) For i = 1 to n
3) Q.Enqueue(i)
4) End For
5) For i = 1 to n-1
6) Let X = Q.Dequeue()
7) End For
8) Let X = Q.Dequeue()
Output: The contents of X

Q.Enqueue(X) add item X to the queue
X = Q.Dequeue() extracts an item from the queue and assigns it to X. 
If the queue is empty then -999 is returned.
```

If n > 0 I understand that this algorithm will output n-1 e.g if n=6, X will be outputted which will be equal to 5.

However, what if n < 0? Can loops go from 1 to negative numbers? If not... I believe none of the For loops would run, giving us a output of -999 (as the queue is empty).

If loops can go into negatives however, then let's say n= -2. The queue would be {1, 0, -1, -2}. We would then have to dequeue 1 to -3 times... Making X (the final item that dequeue was applied on) -2. So now what is this algorithm returning? Pretty much n=X correct?

Comment: Loops can go into negatives and you are correct

Comment: this is big wrong,if we assume for(int i=1;true;i--) your queue have 4 number and can not dequeue 5 number from it,so x=-999

Comment: and in your question you said that If n > 0 I understand that this algorithm will output n-1,are you sure you want to run 8th line?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, if n=-2, you will end up with 4 items in queue. You will then have to dequeue 5. Since the list is empty at this point, the alg will return -999.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but attempting to dequeue more items than there are available in a array would also generate a run time error? Can someone confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

For n>0 the queue will be filled in the following order (lines 1 to 4):

```
1, 2, 3, ..., n
```

in lines 5 to 7 you are extracting one by one (FIFO: first-in first-out):

```
1, 2, 3, ..., n-1
```

and finally in line 8 you extract last element:

```
X = n
```

Like the algorithm is stated I am pretty sure that the `For` statement is only executed for `n >= 1`, but for the case of `n < 1` (and a `For` statement running from `1, 0, -1,..., n`) the queue is filled with `1-n+1 = 2+abs(n)` values and `1-(n-1)+1 = 3+abs(n)` values are extracted in lines 5 to 7, so queue is already empty here. In line 8 a read from the now empty queue will return

```
X = -999
```

But as I said I assume `For i = 1 to n` is not executed at all for `n<1`, so again line 8 will give (because of empty queue):

```
X = -999
```